# What is a good way to do a hotspot on a map

Tags: jquery, html, css

So i have a map of the united states with 4 pins in 4 locations. The image is a png and I need to have a hover info box popup when the user hovers over one of the pins. Is there a standard way of doing this? I was reading online of image hotspots but i wasnt sure if anyone can point me into a clear direction...

Answer (score 1):

It works just like a tooltip. Absolutely position a DIV over the area of the map you want to activate and hook up a tooltip event on mouseover.

There are plenty of scripts and plugn-ins for jQuery available that already do this.

Comment: which jquery pluggins are there...I only found MapHilight ..are there any others

Comment: This has nothing to do with maps. Think of it as an image with hotspots. The hotspots trigger the tooltips. Look here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/tooltip

Answer (score 0):

As Diodeus wrote, just make "absolute" DIV's on top of the map. I can remember if the old MAP tag is supported in HTML5, but that allows to specify circle and polygon shaped areas too. I would still go for DIV solution though. Takes a little CSS knowledge, but is easy once you get it right.

Answer (score 0):

Theres two ways to do it, an `image map`, and layering elements over the image using `absolute positioning` (ala facebook tagging)

Theres a plugin for JQuery which might be of interest.

**[JQuery MapHilight Plugin](http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/demo_usa.html)**

And below is a tutorial to do it yourself, similiar to facebook picture tagging.

**[Tutorial using divs](http://www.nealgrosskopf.com/tech/thread.php?pid=62)**

Answer (score 0):

Position a DIV either off the screen (my preference) or play with the Z-Index as described [here](http://psacake.com/web/jl.asp).  Adjust on hover.

Here's another awesome example:

[click me](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/balloons.html)

Answer (score 0):

There's a new jQuery plugin called [**MobliyMap**](http://playground.mobily.pl/jquery/mobily-map.html) that looks pretty good.  Here's the [demo page](http://playground.mobily.pl/jquery/mobily-map/demo.html).